# Html header part appears in body with space

Tags: php, html

After some updates my landing page just broken. There is a empty head part when inspect element in chrome, and all head items placed in body tag. but when i look for the http response it's all correct.

There is a also space in the beginning of body part which brokes the layout. Here you can see it http://www.sporapp.com/

btw. it's working on local.

Comment: so how do you generate your html?

Comment: All those tags should be in `<head>`

Comment: raw html in php file.  then inlude_once 'indexView.php'

Comment: yeap that's what i told in question @Raffaele . It's already in it. Look for the http response you'll see it.

Comment: [Fix these issues first](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sporapp.com%2F)

Comment: the whitespace before the doctype wont be helping much either

Comment: @pebbl i checked it, there is no white space.

Comment: @tylerdurden Yes there is.. look at the source of your http://www.sporapp.com/ index page... just before your `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"` line you have a newline character.

Comment: ok i see it chrome but there is no new line in Aptana Studio which is strange. And I also opened the file with vim on server, there is no new line.

Comment: Ah, in that case then it looks like you have one of two things happening... (1) somewhere in all of your php includes there are file(s) that have `<?` open or `?>` close php tags with whitespace before *(the open)* or after *(the close)*... this is quite tricky to track down... A search app that supports Regular Expressions might help you find and remove them. (2) You may have a corrupted BOM (Byte Order Mark) at the beginning of your index file... this is much less likely though and is caused by incorrectly encoding normally from transfering files between OSs or Applications.

Comment: ok I'll look for them but it's actually working on local? That's interesting..

Comment: Sending the markup over a remote server can make all the difference in my experience. Anyways, by the sounds of it though - as another poster is actually seeing an unpritable character - this is more likely the BOM issue. I've added a comment below about how to try and fix it... the other problem is that the badly encoded BOM might not be in your index file (it could, as with the whitespace problem) be in another of your includes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see some empty line in response before a doctype declaration. After I copy/pasted HTML from Chrome network tab I found some ? symbol right before doctype (looks like that is some symbol which notepad++ can't display for some reason). Check that file in vim on your server. Suppose you will find a symbol before doctype you do not have on your local machine. Remove it and suppose it will work (it works on my machine, at least head is parsed correctly)
[image]

**From question author:**

For BOM thanks for the Mercurial, it broked the encoding and causes the BOM. And also there was a php file which enclosed ?> then follow by white spaces. After update the broken file and remove the white space, finally it is ok :) ..

Comment: I'm using aptana editor but couldnt see it, just to be sure i copy all text and re created the file  but no luck

Comment: Well.. just checked it. I'm still getting the same symbol. Try to change an editor. Maybe aptana does not show it (in opposite to notepad++ which shows unknown symbol as `?`).

Comment: Also - try to remove `<` in doctype declaration and press backspace few more times, retype `<` and save file again. Suppose it is better to do in vim

Comment: Also - check file format. Possibly it is utf8 with [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Not sure how browser will handle BOM

Comment: done all but nope didnt workout :( , it looks like UTF8.. And aptana claims that it's always without bom https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/1900-encoding-utf-8-with-bom

Comment: Certain browsers will treat it as whitespace... basically to fix it your going to have to copy your whole index file into another file but ignore the first line (you wont be able to delete the BOM character unless you can see it). In the new document retype the first line manually and then save this document over the original. I don't know aptana but certain editors play havock with encoding from other places so best start with a clean slate encoded in the UTF8 way that your editor prefers. If that still fails, switch to another UTF8 editor - do the same - and see if that helps.

Comment: yeap i think it's in one of other files, i searched quickly for the whitespace but not found any. so need to check all files whether it has BOM or not.. Thanks guys, it's a quite demotivating issue.

Comment: ok guys thank you. I fixed it issue is BOM and white space.. For BOM thanks for the Mercurial, it broked the encoding and causes the BOM. And also there was a php file which enclosed ?> then follow by white spaces. After update the broken file and remove the white space, finally it is ok :) .. Anyway if one of you update the answer then I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Run it through a validator: [http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sporapp.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.sporapp.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

I would guess the meta tag errors are causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the empty line you have after the opening body tag :)

Comment: strange! cuz it worked when i just removed it while inspecting the element in chrome..

Comment: it's quite normal that when you removed an text in chrome inspector it just removes. but the problem is there is no space in actual code which you can see in response.